# Calculate appearances of each of 5 variables in combinations of sums where 3 are chosen

Tags: permutations, combinations

I know the selection of any 3 variables can be done in $\binom{5}{3} = 10$ ways. But how many times will each variable appear in the final sum?

Answer (score 0):

If you think about it, there are $\binom{4}{3} = 4$ ways to form a sum without some particular variable, meaning that the variable in question occurs in $10-4=6$ sums.

Edit: Another alternative mode of reasoning goes as such:

We know there is no preference for a single variable over another, meaning all must occur an equal number of times. 10 sums with 3 variables each result in $30$ mentions of $5$ types of variables, meaning that each variable is represented $30/5=6$ times.

Comment: Um if the variables were a,b,c and d. The total cases would be 4, and if we enumerate them, each variable will occur 3 times. How can I push the same logic here to see how many times each variable would occur without enlisting all 10 cases. I didn't get how you concluded there will be 4 ways to form a sum without some particular variable.

Comment: I meant, if you want to form a sum without, for example, $e$, then there are 4 ways: $abc, abd, acd, bcd$. This means that, in the 6 other sums, the letter $e$ is guarenteed to appear.

Comment: Is there any other way, preferably with binomial count to determine total number of times each variable out of a set of "K' such variables, if they have to be paired exactly 'n' times?

Comment: @LakshayKhanna Another way I just thought of goes like this: We know there is no preference for a single variable over another, meaning all must occur an equal number of times. 10 sums with 3 variables each result in 30 mentions of 5 types of variables, meaning that each variable is represented $30/5=6$ times.

Comment: Yes, brilliant. I was only looking for a way to compute like this. Thanks man.